# Trouble loading SimpleXML object for use in foreach loop : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to load a simple XML object from file using      `simplexml_load_file();`
I've been scraping around the internet trying to get a handle on an error with with the subsequent foreach loop.

I'm getting an invalid foreach argument error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:Hosting\bnb\assets\reviews.php on line 2
```

If I try different PHP logic handling the XML object, I can get different errors, however the foreach argument has never shown positive, even though a var_dump has no trouble loading till end of file.

Some other errors have been :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in SERVER_PATH on line 646

Or : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in SERVER_PATH on line 648

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:Hosting\bnb\index.php on line 658
```

PHP is :

```
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file('reviews.xml'); ?>
<?php foreach ($xml->bnb->review as $n_review): ?> 
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <div class="avatar"><a href="#"><img src="img/svg/audio.svg" alt=""></a></div>

                        <div class="comment_right clearfix">
                            <div class="comment_info">
                                <a href="#"> 
                                    <?php echo $n_review->location;?></a><span>|</span>
                                    <?php echo $n_review->date;?> 
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                 <?php echo $n_review->quote; ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Some people mention not using HTTP (as this can be blocked by server settings), or that preparing a string for the memory control abstraction can help :

```
//$feed = file_get_contents('ABSOLUTE_URL');
//$items = simplexml_load_string($feed);
```

Somebody else mentioned some people may have a PHP version that doesn't support anonymous functions.  Is it ever necessary to prepare a new array() or new `SimpleXMLElement()`

Requested Edit:
XML is :

```
<bnb>  
    <review>  
        <quote></quote>  
        <location></location>  
        <date></date>  
    </review>  
    <review>  
        <quote></quote>  
        <location></location>  
        <date></date>  
    </review>  
</bnb>
```

Comment: Can you post a part of the `var_dump` here? It might help.

Comment: please edit your question and post a shortened simplified valid version of that XML. You question cannot be answered without this information. if you insert `var_dump($items)` just before the `foreach` and it yields a SimpleXml object, your code is fine up to that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. is `$xml`okay?

If var_dump($xml) is giving something like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
...
```

then you have successfully loaded the XML into `$xml`.

#### 2. incorrect path in the `foreach` statement:

`$xml` is representing the root node `<bnb>`.
Your statement `$xml->bnb->review`translates to `/bnb/bnb/review`, which doesn't exist in your XML and hence the error-message.

Here's the right path:

```
foreach ($xml->review as $n_review) {
    
    // (...)
}
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/510189

Comment: That was it,  Thanks!  I was learning syntax from examples with deeper structure.  Now for the CSS.